# SAS Creating a lag based on starting price

Tags: sas

My dataset has the price several items at x many locations over n-many weeks.  I wish to create a variable that, for any given location/week, shows the original price (first one listed).  My dataset looks something like this:

```
data have;
    input item $ location $ week price;
cards;
X NC 1 10
X NC 2 10
X NC 3 9.75
X SC 2 8
X SC 3 5
Y NC 1 100
Y NC 2 75
Y NC 3 50
Y NC 4 50
;
run;
```

I want a dataset that looks like this:

```
data want;
    input item $ location $ week price start_price;
cards;
X NC 1 10 10
X NC 2 10 10
X NC 3 9.75 10 
X SC 2 8 8
X SC 3 5 8
Y NC 1 100 100
Y NC 2 75 100
Y NC 3 50 100
Y NC 4 50 100
;
run;
```

I know I can probably use the first. variable to do this somehow, but cannot get it sorted.  Help?

I tried this, but it looks like I need multiple by groups to get location to come out right....do I need to concatenate item/location or is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
data want;
    set have;
    by item;
    if first.item then start_price=price;
    start_price+0;
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `retain` to keep the value from the last row. The result will be the same as the sum statement with `+ 0`, but I think makes more sense.

If I'm understanding the question right, you want first.location to set the start_price. Just use `by item location;` to do this.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by item location;
    retain start_price;
    if first.location then start_price=price;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to demonstrate how you can get the 1st record in a group, here is a [PROC SQL](http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2014/BB/MWSUG-2014-BB03.pdf) solution as well

```
data have;
    input item $ location $ week  price;
cards;
X NC 1 10
X NC 2 10
X NC 3 9.75
X SC 2 8
X SC 3 5
Y NC 1 100
Y NC 2 75
Y NC 3 50
Y NC 4 50
;
run;
```

First with separate queries statements

```
proc sql;
 create table START_PRICE as
 select Item, Location, Price as Start_Price
 from HAVE a
 where Week =
 (select min(week)
 from have b
 where a.item=b.item and a.location=b.location)
 order by a.item, a.location;

 Create table WANT as 
 Select a.item, a.location, a.week, a.price, b.start_price
 From HAVE a left join START_PRICE b
  on a.item=b.item and a.location=b.location
 order by a.item, a.location, a.week;
Quit;
```

Then as one query

```
Proc Sql ;
  Create table WANT2 as
    Select a.Item, a.Location, a.Week, a.Price, b.Start_Price
    from HAVE a
        Left Join
        (select Item, Location, Price as Start_Price
         from HAVE a1
         where Week =
          (select min(week) from have b1
           where a1.item=b1.item and a1.location=b1.location)
          ) b
        on a.item=b.item and a.location=b.location
    order by a.item, a.location, a.week;
Quit;
```